# Filtering rows from dataframe on multiple conditions, getting ValueError

Tags: python, pandas

I'm filtering my rows from dataframe named `joined` on multiple criterias:

```
joined[(joined.gvkey_x==gvkey) & (year-3<=joined.year_y<=year )]
```

I want all the rows from the dataframe which satisfy the given conditions. 
I'm returned this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

I was reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o) which states that I should use `.any()/ .all()` but this isnt exactly clear.

Can someone explain to me how I should apply multiple conditions and what is exactly the purpose and use of `a.any() or a.all()` in my operation (&).

Comment: You need `(joined.year_y >= year-3) & (joined.year_y <= year)`

Comment: Can you show us the head of your dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `query`

```
joined.query('gvkey_x == @gvkey & @year - 3 <= year_y <= @year')
```

***demo***

```
year = 2002
gvkey = 12345

joined = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        gvkey_x=[12343] * 6 + [12345] * 6 + [12346] * 6,
        year_y=list(range(2000, 2006)) * 3
    ))
print(joined)

    gvkey_x  year_y
0     12343    2000
1     12343    2001
2     12343    2002
3     12343    2003
4     12343    2004
5     12343    2005
6     12345    2000
7     12345    2001
8     12345    2002
9     12345    2003
10    12345    2004
11    12345    2005
12    12346    2000
13    12346    2001
14    12346    2002
15    12346    2003
16    12346    2004
17    12346    2005
```

---

```
print(joined.query('gvkey_x == @gvkey & @year - 3 <= year_y <= @year'))

   gvkey_x  year_y
6    12345    2000
7    12345    2001
8    12345    2002
```

---

The reason you were getting your error is because of `(year-3<=joined.year_y<=year )`
`pandas` needs to evaluate each comparison separately.

As @Psidom suggested in the comments:

```
(joined.year_y >= year-3) & (joined.year_y <= year)
```

Would fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `numpy.where` (using sample data):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"year": [2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2013, 2013], "class": ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a'], "value": [13, 25, 32, 12, 23, 54]})
>>> df
  class  value  year
0     a     13  2013
1     b     25  2014
2     b     32  2014
3     b     12  2015
4     b     23  2013
5     a     54  2013
>>> df.ix[np.where((df['class'] == 'a') & (df['year'] == 2013))[0]]
  class  value  year
0     a     13  2013
5     a     54  2013
```